# How can I copy/use already compiled Dlls into my new build in TFS

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a very huge application, having more than 400 different projets. Most of them have been developped in very small solutions, much of them having only from 2 to 5 projects and all having a project called "Main", which is the startup project that calls the other one, for loading time purposes and efficiency.

I have added all of those 400 projects to my TFS build definition manually. 
Now comes 2 questions :

1- It seems in TFS that my projects needs to be placed in the good build order in my build definition? TFS does not automatically detect the dependencies, as my little NAnt was doing all alone??? Do you imagine having to figure out the right build order for a solution containing 400 projects? This would be easy if they would have been in the same solution, but that is not the case.

2- We use third parties assemblies (Dlls). I have added a folder names "CommonDlls" into my TFS workspace. My builds starts correctly and starts compiling my first projects and sending them into the "bin" directory of the build. Perhaps, when the build trys to compile the first project referencing a 3rd party assembly, it cannot find it... Is there a way in pre-build script to copy the files located in the "CommonDlls" folder to the "bin" outdir of the build? Will TFS use those Dlls when compiling each project or it really tryes to use the referecend path into every single project?

Let's say my project on my development machine as "c:\TFS\bin" as a reference path where are located all dlls, will TFS try to look for that folder or it will use the outdir (it's own created bin folder) ?

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way is to package the DLL's logically into NuGet packages. You can then store them on a file share and configure Visual Studio and you build server to fetch the correct ones at build time. This negates the need to burden your source server with big binaries and allows the server to cache the packages between solutions.